# Oracle query to retrieve object attribute in inheritance

Tags: database, oracle

I have type and sub-type defined as

```
   Create or replace type Component_ty as object (
   Code VARCHAR(10),
   Component_Description VARCHAR(100),
   Component_Type VARCHAR(10))
   NOT FINAL;

   Create or replace type External_Component_ty under Component_ty(
   External_Company REF External_Company_ty);
```

where External_company_ty is defined as

```
Create or replace type External_Company_ty as object (
   VAT VARCHAR(15),
   Company_Name VARCHAR(20),
   Component_code VARCHAR(5),
   Address External_Company_address_ty)
   NOT FINAL;
```

and tables are

```
 create table Component of component_ty(
   Code Primary Key, 
   Component_Description NOT NULL,
   Component_Type NOT NULL);

create table External_Company of external_company_ty (
   VAT Primary Key,
   Company_Name NOT NULL,
   Component_Code NOT NULL,
   Address NOT NULL);
```

what can I add to this query in order to show another column with  the external_company.component_code referred to that particular component??

```
select c.*, treat(value(c) as external_component_ty).external_company as external_company FROM component c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the `component_code` attribute:

```sql
select c.*,
       treat(value(c) as external_component_ty).external_company.component_code
         as external_company_comp_code
FROM   component c
```

Which, for the sample data (ignoring the `address` column as you have not defined that object):

```
INSERT INTO external_company VALUES (
  external_company_ty('A', 'Comp A', 'CodeA')
);

INSERT INTO component VALUES (
  external_component_ty(
    'A',
    'ABC',
    'XYZ',
    (SELECT REF(ec) FROM external_company ec WHERE vat = 'A')
 )
);
```

Which outputs:

| CODE | COMPONENT_DESCRIPTION | COMPONENT_TYPE | EXTERNAL_COMPANY_COMP_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ABC | XYZ | CodeA |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CXXkdTT4)

Comment: Great thanks, and what if I want only the elements that have an external_company field?

Comment: @mikerug88 Use the `IS OF` operator. I.e. `WHERE VALUE(c) IS OF (external_component_ty)`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hnuBNLyD)

Comment: sorry I meant those elements that doesn't have an external_company field. I

Comment: @mikerug88 then use `IS NOT OF`